# How to use pdfbox convert the pdf containing the signature image into some pictures

Tags: pdfbox

This is my code:

```
File pdfFile = new File(pdfFileLocation);
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 240);
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
doc.close();
```

but the png file have no signature image.
How should I fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "signature image"? Is it some bitmap image in the page content? Or is it some annotation? Probably the visualization of an integrated digital signature? Or an ink annotation? In the latter case, does it come with an appearance stream? To make analysis easier, can you share a sample document which illustrates the issue?

Comment: and what Pdfbox version are you using?

Comment: My Pdfbox version is 2.0.7. The "signature image" means the visualization of an integrated digital signature.

Comment: This pdf contains CA certificate。

Comment: Is that image displayed with Adobe Reader? If yes, then I'd suspect it is a bug in PDFBox. You should open an issue in JIRA and attach the PDF.

Comment: This image displayed with Adobe Reader.And this image can be clicked.If you click this image,you can receive some certificate infos.

Comment: Then it's definitively a bug. We can't investigate this without the PDF.

Comment: We had a case on the user mailing list and I suspect that JAI isn't installed. (see dependency page)

Comment: Thank you four your answer! When I added dependencies, I successfully solved the problem！